# Console.log me imprime un numero entro 0 en vez de una array que le paso por parametros

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes a tod@s!!

Tengo un problemilla con una array que me paso por parametros a una funcion javascript. El problema es que cuando hago console.log del array dentro de la funcion, me da 0, pero si lo hago desde donde llamo la funcion me devuelve la array. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

Javascript no es mi punto fuerte por el momento.
Este es el codigo:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#mi-select').on('change',function(){
    $.post({
      url : mi_url.ajaxurl,
      data : {
        action: 'mi_funcion',
        param1: param[0],
        param2: param[1]
      }
    })
    .done( function(data){
      //Este console.log('data', data); me devuelve la informacion asi que el ajax esta bien
      //Llamo a una función creada por mi y le paso la array resultante del ajax
      new_table(data);
    })
    .fail( function(error) { console.log('error', error); });
  });
});

function extract_organized_data( data ){

  var array1 = new Array();
  var array2 = new Array();
  var columns = data.message.length;

  //Extraemos los datos y los organizamos en distintas arrays para las iteracciones al crear la tabla.
  for(c=0;c<data.message.length; c++){
    array1.push( data.message[c].asociativo1 );
    array2.push( data.message[c].asociativo2 );
  }

  //Preparamos lo que necesitamos devolver
  var tableData = new Array(array1,array2,columns);

  return tableData;
}

function new_table(data){

  var tableData = extract_organized_data(data);

  jQuery('#este-div').html(function(tableData){
    //Este console.log me devuelve un numero 0
    console.log(tableData);
  }
}
```

Para más información data es una array que contiene un array por indice (message) y por cada indice contiene un array asociativo.

```
data{
  message:
    0: asociativo1:valor ,asociativo2:valor
    1: asociativo1:valor ,asociativo2:valor
}
```

Comment: Perdón me equivoque, no funciona, tenia otro console.log que me ha confundido. Gracias por el enlace me lo guardo en favoritos es muy interesante.

Comment: Puede que cuando busques en el selector `#este-div` se encuentre con un solo match, porque la documentación de [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) dice que el parámetro va a ser el `index` del elemento.

Comment: A que te refieres Kleith?

Comment: Que el valor de `tableData` cuando hacés `console.log(tableData)` va a ser siempre `0`.

Comment: Por qué le pasas una función al `.html()`, qué es lo que querés hacer?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es crear, con esa array que me paso por parametros, una tabla de html con contenidos que hay dentro de la array. ¿Por qué el valor siempre va ha ser 0?

Comment: Gracias por tu solucion Kleith, me ha funcionado perfectamente. Pero porque no hay que pasarle nada? Quiero decir si, por parametros tiene una función, pero no necesita que se le pase la array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de pasarle un parámetro a la función del `.html()` directamente no le coloques nada.

```
function new_table(data){

  var tableData = extract_organized_data(data);

  // elimino el parámetro ya que el primer valor está asignado para devolver el index
  jQuery('#este-div').html(function(){
    //Este console.log me devuelve un numero 0
    console.log(tableData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Una ultima pregunta, porque no hay que pasarle nada? Quiero decir si, por parametros tiene una función, pero no necesita que se le pase la array?

Comment: No hace falta porque esos parámetros que se le pueden o no poner es para que obtengas diferentes respuesta según el método. Es una muy buena pregunta ya que si sos nuevo en javascript, vas a entender que esos son parámetros que recibe una función, en cambio esos son parámetros que devuelve la función, todo lo contrario y no son obligatorios.

Comment: Te dejo un [ejemplo básico](https://codepen.io/kleith/pen/zaxEPe?editors=0010) de cómo es el funcionamiento de esos parámetros.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! :)